# How to fragment the Go workspace

Tags: macos, go, symlink, project-organization

So I've run into an issue with the whole Go workspace and my own personal code organization. So I understand how the workspace is supposed to be set up as, with src, pkg, and bin, under one overarching gocode folder.

However, this doesn't really integrate well with my workflow. In my code folder, I have two other folders: Work and Personal. Work of course is the folder that contains all of the projects that I am working on for my job, and personal is for personal side projects or fun testing. In both folders I have Go projects, along with JavaScript, python, and HTML projects. I do not really want to cross Work and Personal together in the same Go folder because I would like to cd into Work and see all of my projects (either for reference or ease of access) and same with Personal. I do not want to switch between one folder filled with a clash of Work and Personal Go code, and then another Work folder with loads of Javascript.

But when I organize my projects as I explained, I essentially break the whole GOPATH functionality which in turns messes with import statements, etc. So is there anyway that I can continue organizing my projects as they are and trick Go into thinking that they are all in a central Go/src folder? I believe I could do something with symlinks as I am on Mac o x but I do not know if that works or not. Any developer solve this problem in their own company? Thanks!

Comment: You can use symlinks _to_ directories in your GOPATH, just make sure you don't have symlinks inside your GOPATH. Other than that, fighting against the Go tools is only going to cause more trouble than its worth.

Comment: yeah, put everything in your gopath, then `ln -s $GOPATH/src/github.com/foots/project ~/Work/project`

Comment: @JimB Okay, so let me see if I understand this properly, I am slightly new to Unix. Instead of actually putting my code in `~/Code/Work/MyProject` I would put my code in `~/gocode/src/MyProject`? Then if I symlink the code to my custom workspace, when I `cd` into my custom workspace, it would automatically redirect the terminal to the GOPATH?

Comment: @Mr.Foots: yes (sort of). I would highly recommend learning a bit about *nix environments while you're at it. Note that there are a few things that could trip you up being in a symlinked path, but in those rare cases you can switch directories into the real path in GOPATH.

Comment: Alright so I did some experimentation and it seems like the symlink (created with Plato's command with the target dir lacking the `/project` as Mac os x apparently creates its own folder named after the folder used in the symlink) works perfectly. So thank you @JimB and @Plato.

Answer (score 1):

https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/blog/18

That blog lists how you can set up multiple paths into your `$GOPATH` variable to let you do what you want.  The idea is that you have some default workspace (which is where all your `go get` packages will be put), and then any additional workspaces you have can follow that default workspace in the environment variable (colon-separated on unix-based).  The Go tool is specifically designed to handle this use case, and will check each path in your `$GOPATH`, in order, for dependencies, using the first version of that dependency that it finds.

The only major thing you'll have to be aware of if you do this is that you can't use `$GOPATH` as an actual path string anymore (you have to split it up first).  Some Go packages may not be able to handle this setup.  However, if you ever need to find a file in any of the paths in your `$GOPATH` yourself, this function will do so:

```
func FindInGoPath(filePath string) (string, error) {
    pathList := strings.Split(os.ExpandEnv("${GOPATH}"), string(os.PathListSeparator))

    if strings.TrimSpace(pathList) == "" {
        return "", errors.New("$GOPATH environment variable is empty/not set")
    }

    for _, path := range pathList {
        if !strings.HasSuffix(path, string(os.PathSeparator)) {
            path += string(os.PathSeparator)
        }
        if _, err := os.Stat(path + filePath); err == nil {
            return path + filePath, nil
        }
    }
    return "", errors.New("file not found")
}
```